# Android's InputMethodService keyEventCode won't work

Tags: android

I'm trying to create my keyboard, and now am at the place when the pressed button should send the letter to the application.

In the examples I found

```
InputMethodService.sendDownUpKeyEvents(keyEventCode);
```

But couldn't really figure out, what should go into keyEventCode?

For example, how do I send a letter "A" ?

edit: **Just one more thing, here ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html ) I can find only codes for english character. How do I get other unicode characters?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function takes the constants from the [`KeyEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) class.
To send `a`, use

```
sendDownUpKeyEvents(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A);
```

Comment: Just one more thing, here ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html ) I can find only codes for english character. How do I get other unicode characters?

Comment: Theres a `KeyEvent.getUnicodeChar()` function, that should help. Never worked with it myself though. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getUnicodeChar(int)

Comment: hmm... says "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getUnicodeChar() from the type KeyEvent".

Comment: It's not a static function. You have to create a instance of it (`KeyEvent k = new KeyEvent(..)`) and then use `k.getUnicodeChar()`. If I understand this correctly, you have to set your wanted keycombination in the constructor of the class (where i wrote `..`). Check the docs for the constructor that suits you best.

Comment: thanks. :) just how do I display this "k" later? sendDownUpKeyEvents asks for an int, rather then KeyEvent.

Comment: Supply the response from `k.getUnicodeChar()` to `sendDownUpKeyEvents()`, e.g. just writing `sendDownUpKeyEvents(k.getUnicodeChar())` should suffice.

Comment: ok... but then where should I put the unicode code? for example, "U+003F" for the "?" ?

Comment: @alextsc let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3027/discussion-between-roger-and-alextsc)

Comment: I'm sorry I never implemented that myself. I can only look at the docs and try to figure it out. It's also a bit much to write a whole tutorial here in the comments. I recommend opening a new question for this.

Comment: opened :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256957/androids-inputmethodservice-how-to-get-unicode-characters